# Lottery tickets and the binomial coefficient

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

A ticket in a lottery consists of 7 of the first 36 positive integers.

**Questions:**

**1. Show that the number of possible tickets are $\pmatrix{36\\ 7}$.**

My answer:

To get the number of ways to choose 7 numbers out of 36 numbers, you take the number of ways you can sort all of the lottery numbers and divide by both the number of ways to sort the lottery numbers that are not selected, and the number of ways you can sort 7 numbers (because we don't care about the order).

**2. Let $x$ be one of the numbers $0,1,\dots,7$. Show that the number of tickets with $x$ correct (winning) numbers are $\pmatrix{7\\ x}\pmatrix{29\\ 7-x}$.**

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have to choose which correct numbers ($x$ in total) there are in the ticket, that is ${7 \choose x}$. Then we have to choose the other non winning numbers in the ticket, they are $7-x$ and in total there are $36-7=29$ non winning numbers to choose from, so we have ${29 \choose 7-x}$ possibilities. To find the total number of tickets we just do the multiplication ${7 \choose x}{29 \choose 7-x}$.